# In c how to assign 2d array based of a 1d array?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

So lets say i have an array like

```
int x1[5] = {0,0,0,3,2};
int x2[5] = {0,0,0,3,2};
int x3[5] = {0,0,0,3,2};
int x4[5] = {0,0,0,3,2};

int listofx[4][5];
```

pretty much i want listofx to store each array of x at one of its positions when I am using assign i get an error saying there incompatible types

Comment: What about `int x[][] = {{0, 0, 0, 3, 2}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 2}, ...}`?

Comment: I was just using 0,0,0,3,2 as an example the program would have different values of x after doing some stuff and woulsint have predeclared values so i want to assign them after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
int *px[] = { x1, x2, x3, x4 };
```

and if you want to access your number, do this:

```
px[1][4]; //1 is x2, 0 is x1
```

Comment: Your the best <3 i would make u my valentine THANK YOU